# return statement in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, return

I am trying to understand about return in scala. here i wrote a simple function to add two int.

```
def sum(x: Int, y: Int ): Int = {
 val sum = x+ y
}
```

but i get error

```
cmd2.sc:3: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
```

if i write the same program like below

```
def sum(x: Int, y: Int ): Int = {
 val sum =x
 sum +y
}
```

it is fine.

is it that in scala return statement can not have more than one expression?
Can someone help me what is wrong in first code

Answer (score 6):

Most of the languages define things like:

- statement - we can intuitively think it's a piece of program that can exist on its own
- expression - it's a piece of program that has a value (which can be used to combine it with other values, passed around, etc)

(These aren't textbook definitions but let's not get too detailed here).

Scala tries to eliminate this distinction as much as possible, so e.g. `println("foo")` is an expression of type `Unit` while in Java it would be a statement and have no value. But there are some places where this distinction couldn't be avoided.

`val`/`var` definition is not an expression but a statement. So you cannot do something like:

```
val a = val b = 2 // illegal start of simple expression
```

However, you can make it a part of a block of code, telling language where its scope begins and ends (using brackets or Scala 3 braceless syntax):

```
val a = {
  val b = 2
}
```

Type and value of the block of code are taken from the last value computed by this block. (Meaning that *parts* of the block might not all be expression but a *whole* block can be used as a value/expression). Usually that's its last expression. But if it's a statement like `val` definition, it is inferred to `Unit`:

```
val a: Unit = {
  val b: Int = 2
}
```

Notice that it's different than saying that assignment would discard the value:

```
var b: Int = 0
val a = (b = 10)
```

because assignment of a value to the `var` is an expression... although it's also of type `Unit`. The difference is subtle but you can see it e.g. in:

```
import scala.util.chaining._

(val a = 2).tap(println) // <- this would not compile
var b = 0
(b = 2).tap(println) // <- this would print: ()
```

Notice the difference between `()` and `{}`:

- `()` are used to group/change priority of operators in an expression, it doesn't create a new scope
- `{}` allow you to use statements and define order in which they are executed, it creates a new scope

It's important because:

```
{ val a = 2 }.tap(println) // prints: ()
```

would compile and without understanding that difference it is confising.

In your case you created a block which type was interred to `Unit` and value to `()` while your function expected `Int`. Making sure that the last line as an expression evaluating to the right value would be a solution:

```
// {} are not needed if whole body is a single expression
def sum(x: Int, y: Int ): Int = x + y
// but you can use it if you want
def sum(x: Int, y: Int ): Int = {
  x + y
}
// and even use variables as long as
// the expression with the value is last element
def sum(x: Int, y: Int ): Int = {
  val z = x + y
  z
}
// in Scala 3 braces can be replaced with indentation
def sum(x: Int, y: Int ): Int =
  val z = x + y
  z
```

Answer (score 4):

It is because the last statement shouldn't be an assignment, this should work:

```scala
def sum(x: Int, y: Int ): Int = x + y
```

Comment: The braces are not needed: `def sum(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y`